# Change UICollectionViewCell layout on orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, orientation, uicollectionviewcell

I'm developing an app in which I have a UICollectionView. The UICollectionView has different types of UICollectionViewCells in it. For one of the Cell, I need to have different layout for different orientation.

In portrait view the cell should have the following layout

[image]

For landscape I need this layout

[image]

What is the best way to do this? Also, I have to make this work on iOS 7 devices as well. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: do you have two collectionViewCells for these two layouts?

Comment: Right now, no. But I can add that. How to load a new layout on orientation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be my logic:

Add one more collectionViewCell For the landscape layout with a different reuseIdentifier.

Declare a BOOL variable like :
`BOOL isLAndscape;`

in the implementation section.By default the bool value is `NO` or `False`.

Then check for the Notification if Orientation Changed!
You Can set This Thing in viewDidLoad like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(OrientationDidChange:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and whenever Orientation of your Device changed **OrientationDidChange** Called where You can do whatever You Want as Per Orientation.In your case ,if the orientation is landscape,then isLAndacape=YES; and then reload the collectionView.

```
-(void)OrientationDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation Orientation=[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];

    if(Orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || Orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
    isLAndscape=YES;
    [collectionVIew reloadData];
     }
    else if(Orientation==UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    {
    isLAndscape=NO;
    [collectionVIew reloadData];
    }
  }
```

And in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method of the collectionView,add the condition check for the bool `islAndacape` and change the reuseIdentifier.

```
NSString *reuseIdentifier;
if(isLAndscape)
{
reuseIdentifier=@"landscapeReuseId";
}
else
{
reuseIdentifier=@"portraitReuseId";
}
```

Thats it!!

**DISCLAIMER!!! this is my logic.I have not tried this.Check if it works.**

Comment: Thanks @abhi1992. That works. But is reloading UICollectionView on orientation a good option?

Comment: Or you should add constraints on runtime to fit the layout which is a bit complex code for me.I don't know actually.Reloading collectionview is a simple code and not a complex stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change collectionViewLayout on landscape rotation